# How to highlight specific texts from a excel formula (Both in Excel and Google Sheet)?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a sentence automated for **"amount" + "date"**. I'm able to do with simple Excel formula but I'm not able to highlight the "amount" and "date" which is part of the formula.

My formula is:

`="The total price is " &TEXT(J5,"0.00") & " date today is " &TEXT(H3, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

[image: data]

Is there a code/VBA function that will bypass this issue? The **total amount and date interchanges daily** and I just need it highlighted. If the only solution is VBA codes, how do I make sure the Macros won't disappear when I uploaded the Excel file to google drive?

Comment: https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/format_characters_in_a_cell

Comment: Would you be open to using Google Apps Script? (and not using [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), which cannot be used to set rich value texts).

Answer (score 1):

You can spread your sentence over four cells and apply formatting to the required cells, which can be filled with a formula, and no macros involved.

[image: split sentence]

Otherwise, it is impossible to apply styles from a formula.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible in Google Sheets by any means to have it colored and at the same time to have it in one cell

Comment: Wrong. That is possible. What is not possible is having it as a formula+color different (richtext)